# Bash: syntax error: "(" unexpected question in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm newer to the scripting side of Bash. Receiving a syntax error on line 2.  But, not sure what the issue is.  Help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prints userlist, add users to system, add users to wheel group, and sets password.

userlist=(john mary dan jenna gary)
for i in {$userlist[@]}
do 
echo ${userlist[@]}
 sudo useradd ${userlist[@]}
 usermod -aG wheel ${userlist[@]}
 passwd ${userlist[@]}
done
```

Comment: `for i in {$userlist[@]}` ==> `for i in ${userlist[@]}`. The rest of your `for` loop should be referencing `$i`, not `${userlist[@]}`.

Comment: Also, you're not using `i` anywhere; do you mean to use `"$i"` instead of `${userlist[@]}` within the for loop?

Comment: You should paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ in the future before asking, it'll help you fix a lot of issues.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: It sounds like you aren't actually running the script with `bash`; are you using, for example, `sh myscript` to start it? That would ignore the shebang and use `sh`, which isn't `bash` in Ubuntu.

Comment: For example, in `dash` typing `user=(1 2 3)` produces `dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
for i in {$userlist[@]}
```

should be:

```
for i in ${userlist[@]}
```

Since `userlist` is an array, `$userlist` expands to the first element, `john`, so `{$userlist[@]}` becomes `{john[@]}` which isn't what you want, presumably.

Also, inside the for loop you should be using `$i` to reference each element in the `$userlist` array.

Comment: Don't add that as a comment. There's an edit button beneath your answer. Use it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist was just being lazy, thanks for the nudge.  Edited my answer :)

Comment: Also, all variable references should be wrapped in double-quotes (i.e. `"${userlist[@]}"` and `"$i"`). It doesn't matter with the example data, but if you ever need to handle strings that contain spaces or wildcards, it'll save a lot of headaches.

Comment: This is a typo, but it wouldn't explain the error mentioned in the title.

Comment: @chepner yeah, since OP mentions Ubuntu I'm guessing your comment about `dash` is the likely explanation for the title, and the title is incorrect in mentioning bash.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be this script easier ?

```
for i in john mary dan jenna gary
do 
echo $i
 sudo useradd $i
 usermod -aG wheel $i
 passwd $i
done
```